# Export resultset to CSV

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, tkinter

I'm new with Python and I created an interface app using TKinter. The way the app works is it allows me to add products and their specifications to a database and later display the entire content of the database. I also have some functions assigned to different buttons allowing me to filter the information and display specific records from the database (based on columns' name etc.). This is an example of one of these functions:

```
def Search():
    
    if SEARCH.get() != "":
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
        Database()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product_name` LIKE ?", ('%'+str(SEARCH.get())+'%',))
        fetch = cursor.fetchall()
        for data in fetch:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data))
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

I want to be able to export the resultset to a CSV file and this is where I get stuck. I tried this but the query is wrong and it exports the entirety of my database every time. I only want to export the records in the resultset.

```
def Export():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("facturi.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `product`")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
            a.writerow(line)
   
    dir_path = os.getcwd() + "/report.csv"
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Succes', 'Data exported successfully')

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

I'm new so any help is welcome. Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you use the same SQL statement as in the `Search()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your query in the function Export( ) takes all data from database. Add “where” clause so that you can filter data as you did in Search( ) function.